# How to check each element in array?

Tags: c++, arrays, maze

I'm trying to analyze each element that has been placed into my array from a txt file of chars for a maze game. The array must be checked so we can determine where in the maze the walls are, players are, ghosts, keys and ladders, entrance, etc. So I need to check for certain characters (such as #, P, K, D, G, E). I'm not sure how to set this up though?

Here are the functions to get the Floor files and place each character in the array called tiles.

```
const int ROWS = 20;

void Floor::Read (const char * filename)
{
size_t row = 0;
ifstream input(filename);

while (row < ROWS && input >> tiles[row++]);

}
void Game::readFloors()
{
m_floor[0].Read("FloorA.txt");
m_floor[1].Read("FloorB.txt");
m_floor[2].Read("FloorC.txt");

}
```

Then here is what one of the floors looks like with each char:

```
##############################
#      K                     #
#  ############## ### ###  # #
#      K    #   # #C# #K#  # #
# ######### # A # # # # #  # #
#      K    #   #          # #
# ############D#####D####### #
#                            #
#   C         G        C     #
#                            #
# ######D##############D#### #
#      #  C         #K#    # #
# #### ######## #   # #      #
# #K   #      # ### # # #### #
# # ## # #### #   # # #    # #
E # ## # #    ### # # #### # #
# #    # #K           D    # #
# #D#### ################### #
#                    K       #
##############################
```

header file with the two classes used with the functions above:

```
class Floor {
char tiles[20][30]; 
void printToScreen();
public:
Floor();
void Read (const char * filename);
};

class Game {
private:
Floor m_floor [3];
vector<Character> characters; 
public:
void readFloors();
};
```

Looked for similar questions, but most aren't analyzing many different options. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why are you operating with raw `char*` pointers instead of using `std::string` in 1st place? Also using `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>` should make your life a lot easier.

Comment: Well, I figured since the maps are already char's I want to leave them as the char type when passing through functions.

Comment: You probably need two stars then: `char**`. A `std::vector<std::string>` for a single _floor_ would suffice as well.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ You meant std::vector<std::vector<char>>.

Comment: @LogicStuff No, I meant for all present _floors_.

Comment: Okay, so this line `vector<Character> characters;` should be changed to `vector<string>characters;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've put together a simple reader that puts the map (based on your example) into a matrix you can juggle with.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

std::ifstream f("/path/../txt.txt");
std::string str;

int cols = 0;
int rows = 0;

char mat[100][100];

int main(){
    int line = 0;
    while(std::getline(f, str)){
        const char * chars = str.c_str();
        for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++){
            mat[line][i] = chars[i];
        }

        cols = str.length();
        line++;
        rows++;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<line; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<rows; j++){
            std::cout<<mat[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
    std::cout<<"Cols: "<<cols<<" Rows: "<<rows;
    return 0;
}
```

This way, you can get the position of each player, wall block etc. by a two point coordinates just by performing simple character comparisons.

Comment: Wow, this is very thorough. Thank you so much for this answer. So I would have to change my functions then, I guess. Since this is all in main, I'll have to switch it so it's in my Floor class.

Comment: How would the comparisons work though, because you have it display each column and row, so would I just say `if row == '#'` and same for column?

Comment: You access an element of a matrix by assigning two points to the specific location. eg of comparison. mat[i][j] == '#' where 0<=i<rows, 0<=j<columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for loop inside of a for loop, one to check the columns in the array and another to check the rows. Them you'd just check each element if it equals k,c,g,etc.